# trigger on contact for counting of activities history and also updated on Account and opportunity object

Tags: apex-code, apex-trigger

field for number of Activities for each Contact, regardless of Type or Status.
Full Details: The requirement is to be able to create reports based on Contacts or account or Opportunities and see a “Summary” field for Total  # of Activities associated with either Contacts, Accounts or Opportunities.
Note that we do not want to see a line for each activity, we want to see one line for the each contact or opp or account with the activity summary count.
Note:  The original request also included the ability to have a unique activity count on reports

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code, but you could do something like this for an insert (you'd need to also cover updates and deletes). In this example, NumberOfActivites__c is your custom Task count field on the Contact object:

```
Map<Id,Integer> countMap = new Map<Id,Integer>();
List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();

for (Task t : trigger.new){
    //get id's of all contacts affected by the batch
    Id w = t.whoId;
    if (w.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() == 'Contact'){
        //since there could be more than one task related to a contact 
        //in a batch, you would have to count them
        if (countMap.keyset().containts(w)){
            countMap.get(w) += 1;
        } else {
            countMap.put(w,1);
        }
    }
}

//get list of contacts to be updated
contactList = [Select Id, NumberOfActivities__c
               From Contact
               Where Id In :countMap.keyset()];

//modify contacts in list with new count
for (Contact c : contactList){
    c.NumberOfActivites__c = c.NumberOfActivites__c + countMap.get(c.Id));
}

//do the update
update contactList;
```